# How to store constant strings retrieved at run time so they are globally available?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a .netcore Api application which reads environment variables or a large json configuration file and retrieves some constant values like connection string, client id, client secret etc.

These values are then used by several controllers.

I am reading the configuration file on startup and then I deserialize this json.

What is an ideal approach to storing these values so all controllers can have access to them ? A static class ? A dictionary ? Something else ?

Comment: Why not use the built in `IOptions<T>` from [`Microsoft​.Extensions​.Configuration`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration) you can pass the JSON configuration right in to it with a `.AddJsonFile(`. See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration)

Comment: Two reasons. I want to add another json file specific to these settings, which are aside from what I am saving in the appsettings.json, I am not able to find a way to do this.

Second reason is, I want the developer to have intellisense as these settings will eventually get converted into a DTO

Comment: The way to add another json file is you just add a 2nd `.AddJsonFile("YourOtherSettingsFile.json")` to the configuration builder. And the developers do get intelisense, thats why I said use `IOptions<T>` the `T` is your class that represents the settings, giving other developers all the settings that are defined in that class via intelisense. Using the `ConfigurationBuilder` also lets you override json values with environment variable values by putting `.AddEnvironmentVariables();` after the `.AddJsonFile(` (you mentioned that in your first line of the question)

Comment: Tried and this works perfectly.

Comment: You should likely delete your question.